# How to fix SQL Executions Error in PostgreSQL due to camel case names of table and columns?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql

[image]

I just started to use `PostgreSQL` in my project, but i've this error when retrieving data from table. Is someone have suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Does that AssetTransactions table exist? Have you read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101570/error-42p01-relation-does-not-exist ?

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` script for `AssetTransactions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems table name and column names are in `CamelCase`.

PostgreSQL treat all the statements in lower case generally, As you can see the error where table name is shown in lower case.

So if above is the case then cover all such table name and column names with `""`. so your query should be:

```
select "Id", "AccountID", "IsPurchase", "Stock_Symbol","Stock_PricePerShare","Shares","DateProcessed" from "AssetTransactions"
```

Please note that if any column name is in smallcase then no need to cover in `""`.

If your schema is other than `public` then your table name should be like `"schema_name"."table_name"`

Comment: haha its worked, thank dude, i can't realize that before

Comment: its a good practice to use small case names always to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

`AssetTransactions` table does not exist, or it may not be present in the current default `schema`.

Use query with schema `SELECT * FROM public.AssetTransactions`

Comment: well, ive trying that script but its not worked. but thank for giving me a suggestion for the problem haha

Answer (score 0):

> The database query is on an undefined table. This error occurs due to improper database setup, unidentified table name, and so on.

For instance, the customer query on table name ‘pgtable‘ like:

`SELECT * FROM  pgtable`

This query is totally correct in case of a public schema. But, for a non-public schema ‘xx’ the query must be:

`SELECT * FROM  "xx"."pgtable"`

> so first check that you have proper database setup, then check that you didnt quote any identifiers because then you'll have to use it as how u quoted it, then check your schema

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem
The problem is solved if the table names are in lower case
Make sure all words are in lower case