# Postgres refuses to find existing table, why?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a Postgres database and following tables inside of it, created using python Alembic ORM. Everything looks great at the first moment, but when trying to access any of the given tables, it throws: `Did not find any relation named`.

```
                    List of relations
 Schema |            Name             |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+-----------------------------+----------+----------
 public | CreditTransactions          | table    | postgres
 public | CustomerApplications        | table    | postgres
 public | CustomerApplications_ID_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | alembic_version             | table    | postgres
(4 rows)
```

```
\d CustomerTransactions
```

Result:
`Did not find any relation named "CustomerTransactions".`

```
\d CustomerApplications
```

Result:
`Did not find any relation named "CustomerApplications".`

How my tables look like:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Boolean, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Model = declarative_base()

class CreditTransaction(Model):

    __tablename__ = "CreditTransactions"

    ID = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    bad = Column(Boolean, default=False)

class CustomerApplication(Model):

    __tablename__ = "CustomerApplications"

    ID = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    annual_income = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    total_children = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    age = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    has_realty = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    has_car = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    has_mobile_phone = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

Alembic Migrations seems to be okay, as I don't see any errors.

What in your opinion can cause this problem?

Comment: postgresql://postgres:Kir@localhost:5434/ml_db

Comment: if something is wrong with permissions, I guess it would't be able to create tables

Comment: okay, let me clarify: tables were created using alembic, using commands: `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Migrations"` and then applying migrations to the database using `alembic upgrade head`. "postgres" is superuser in my database and it did created these tables.

Comment: Try `\d "CustomerTransactions"`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, it does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that for some reason my Postgres database do not recognize camel case table names. After giving corresponding lowercase names "applications" and "transactions" the error gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Postgres does not recognize capitalized table names, it is treated as case-sensitive wrapping the table name in double quotes helps, you can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63095646/21566703) answer for more context.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike a few other databases, PostgreSQL is case-sensitive regarding tables, views, and the naming of other objects.

The most optimal way to get around this is to use a consistent lowercase for all table names and use the same in queries as well.